# Creating a camera activity optimized / suitable for OCR

Tags: android, ocr, android-camera, tesseract

I'm trying to create a camera activity for taking photos to be OCR'd. Here's what I wish to accomplish:

1. A resizable box in the middle of the camera preview to indicate which particular area will be created into a Bitmap and processed by the OCR engine.
2. Continuous autofocus (done)

I'm using tesseract btw.

If anyone would care to point me to some reference / examples / tutorials, that would be great.

Comment: can you tech me or link me to some sources to make a resizable box in the middle of the camera preview to indicate which particular area will be created into a Bitmap and processed by the OCR engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a viewfinder rectangle here:

https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr/blob/master/android/src/edu/sfsu/cs/orange/ocr/CaptureActivity.java

Comment: thanks, I've forked tess-two (which includes eyes-two). Though I'm looking for a less abstracted example. Currently going through all the related classes.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing something similar. Right now, I'm just sending the whole photo to a webservice and processing it with [OCRfeeder](http://code.google.com/p/ocrfeeder/), which will perform segmentation on the image and send each part with text in it to tesseract. I've been getting much better accuracy that way. In addition, you might want to perform [some preprocessing to clean up the image first.](https://github.com/ludflu/ocrprep)

Answer (score 0):

There can be two general approaches.

You can resize the image before sending it to OCR engine. Keep in mind that Tesseract engine you use has some kind of feature - it requires some space between characters and image borders, sometimes more than expected.

The second approach is to use field-level recognition, when you specify coordinates of the text block and send the full image to OCR engine. Have a look at http://www.ocrsdk.com, it's a cloud OCR SDK with web api recently launched by ABBYY, it's in beta, so for now it's free to use. It has a [field level recognition methods](http://ocrsdk.com/help/ApiReference/method_processTextField.html) and [Android code samples](https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com/tree/master/Android). I work @ ABBYY and can provide additional info on our products if necessary